# Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm-hotspot

In Eclipse, I got this error running my project:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGiW2.png)

I started getting this error after installing JDK 14.

Comment: `-Xverify:none` / `-noverify` options are dangerous and [should never be used](https://blogs.oracle.com/buck/never-disable-bytecode-verification-in-a-production-system). When bytecode verification is off, JVM becomes vulnerable to invalid bytecode, and may easily crash, e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321205/jvm-crash-problematic-frame-canonicalizerdo-if), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58855063/jvm-exception-access-violation-crash-in-spring-boot-application). The message warns that these options are deprecated since JDK 13. Just remove them from the JVM command line.

Comment: @apangin That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I didn't use -Xverify:none or -noverify, I got this error while running eclipse, I recently installed eclipse Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0) with JDK14 and I get this error while running a project.

Comment: That message is only output if you are specifying the option. Check the 'Run > Run Configuration' for your program - look at the Arguments tab.

Comment: You got a warning *and* an error. They are just printed beneath each other. Coincidence does not imply causality. Your application does not run because the main class has not been found. But well, for both problems, you have to check and fix the run configuration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61211695/openjdk-64-bit-server-vm-warning-options-xverifynone-and-noverify-were-depre)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, you've got a warning and an error.

**Warning:**

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release
```

This can be addressed by disabling the application's "Fast startup" checkbox. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63156958/3342253) for details.

**Error:**

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.cgs.stestweb.SpringBootBasicsApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cgs.stestweb.SpringBootBasicsApplication
```

To address this, you will need to correct your configuration.