# Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a project from "https://start.spring.io/" and run it from the main method without adding anything, but I get an error like this.
I am using JDK11,
I am using Intellij,
Virtualization is enabled.
the output is as follows:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.2.12.RELEASE)

2020-12-11 22:35:48.638  INFO 14028 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on DESKTOP-1HHLJVV with PID 14028 (C:\Users\xsamu\Desktop\demo\demo\target\classes started by xsamu in C:\Users\xsamu\Desktop\demo\demo)
2020-12-11 22:35:48.639  INFO 14028 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-11 22:35:49.148  INFO 14028 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-12-11 22:35:49.155  INFO 14028 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-12-11 22:35:49.155  INFO 14028 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2020-12-11 22:35:49.212  INFO 14028 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-12-11 22:35:49.212  INFO 14028 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 548 ms
2020-12-11 22:35:49.312  INFO 14028 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-12-11 22:35:49.425  INFO 14028 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-12-11 22:35:49.428  INFO 14028 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 0.981 seconds (JVM running for 1.39)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using JDK11?  My JDK 11 does not give that error when starting with those options.  These command line options were removed in JDK 13 - see [this link](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8214731) for more details.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. And I found the solution to the problem. See the solution here > https://stackoverflow.com/a/62315674/12917767

Comment: Yes it is. Done