# Enable Actuator health endpoint without enabling auto config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In my project, I don't want to use `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. My Application.java has `@ComponentScan`, `@Configuration` and `@Import` annotation.

I have added spring boot actuator dependency in my pom.xml. But, when I try to access `http://<>/acutuator/health`, I get 404. I believe I need to specify some config class as part of Import annotation. I would need help in figuring out what that config would be.

Answer (score 0):

`@EnableAutoConfiguration` makes Spring guess configuration based on the classpath, and that's what spring boot all about. If you find that specific auto-configuration classes that you do not want are being applied, you can use the exclude attribute of `@EnableAutoConfiguration` to disable them. For example:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Thanks Luay. I have a long list to exclude but a small list to include. I would also like to keep control on what am I running. So, I would like to include selectively as done in answer of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230702/speed-up-spring-boot-startup-time.