# improving spring boot start up time

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that uses hibernate with oracle and hibernate envers. The application takes a long time to starup. from the logs, I can see something like this

```
2020-06-05 09:51:40,727 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
2020-06-05 09:52:20,219 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl - Envers integration enabled? : true
2020-06-05 09:53:02,809 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
```

if we see the timestamp between log statements the difference is pretty large.

can anyone suggest how I can improve the startup time?

Comment: did u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230702/speed-up-spring-boot-startup-time