# How can I import a inner class in SpringBoot by @Import?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

To speed up SpringBoot start up, I try to stop Springboot's auto-config, and import beans by  @Import as described in [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230702/speed-up-spring-boot-startup-time). How can I import a inner calss likes AopAutoConfiguration.ClassProxyingConfiguration?

@Import AopAutoConfiguration.ClassProxyingConfiguration dose not work. Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Stopping Spring Boot auto-config won't give you that much of a performance boost as you would think. Checking classes and component-scanning is pretty fast actually (despite what people think). So I would focus your energy elsewhere to really improve the performance. Depending on your version of Spring Boot there is already a startup endpoint (if actuator is used) which identifies beans that take longer, or you should benchmark/check the logging for parts that take long (generally Hibernate, JDBC and opening DB connections are the parts that take a long time).

Comment: good advice. I wil try it. Thanks